# What type of garage heater should I connect to my 30A circuit?

Tags: garage, heater

i want to heat my garage with a garage heater.  My garage is already wired with a NEMA 6-30 plug on a dedicated 30 Amp breaker.  What can i use to heart my garage  using this existing set up?

What kind of heater, what do you think I should  buy?
i have seen three kinds for sale:

1. construction heaters which are 240v 30 amp breaker, wired to a receptacle with a NEMA 6-30 plug. but i am told that these are dangerous and do NOT conform to the construction code.  they sell for about $150
2. a wired in heater hanging from the ceiling (i would use the existing breaker and wire but remove the receptacle and hard wire it in) 240v 30 amp. These are expensive to buy (about $300) and i would need to hire an electrician to hard wire instead of using existing plug
3. 240 V dimplex garage heater.  These take a 20 amp breaker. I would need to switch out the 30 amp breaker, and change the receptacle.

is there a better option?

Comment: I am not sure why a listed portable electric heater would be dangerous. I have one in my garage that I move around to help in the winter when staining and painting. The SO cord needs to be 10 awg.

Comment: in the area where i live you can not get your electrical permit approved if you use a plug in construction heater.  i can't figure it out either. but i know that if you don't have a permit and there is ever a fire for "any reason" they will disallow your claim.  so for the small price of a heater i want to stay "legal"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with NEMA 6-30.   10-30 is bad.

Comment: @guy the difference is, EdBeal is using the heater in a way that is regarded as temporary, for instance moving it around regularly for spot heating. . Whereas you and OP are looking for a parmanent install as your primary heating method.

Comment: I bought this one with a damaged box for $80 and installed it in my 2-car garage located in Ohio.  I have no insulation in the walls or the ceiling, but the metal garage door is insulated.  At 20 degrees, it can hold at about 55/60.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00064NURU/

Answer (score 1):

Common electric convection baseboard heaters are ridiculously cheap, in the neighborhood of $50 for a 2000W unit and $15 for a 30A thermostat.

Select your heaters so they total up to less than 80% of 7200W.

That plus some EMT conduit, a few junction boxes and some red 10AWG THWN wire to hook it all up, done.

Comment: The op asked about a construction heater. These are portable 30 amp cord ang plug devices and listed as portable and code legal since they are listed.

Comment: @EdBeal I thought he was asking for better options.   There.  I fixed some formatting errors in his post so it displays as he intended.